# Dimensions as criteria for iPhoto smart album?

Tags: mac, photos.app, photos, ilife

In iPhoto '11 (latest version, on Mac OS Lion), can I make a smart album for all photos of a certain size (e.g. 960x640)? Can I make a smart album containing photos of multiple sizes?

#### EDIT

I answered my own question. See my answer below. Yes, it's possible.

Comment: What version of Mac OS and iPhoto are you using?

Comment: Have you actually tried creating a smart folder yet?

Comment: I don't want a smart folder. I want a smart album. I have made smart folders, and they don't exactly appear as albums in iPhoto or sync over to my iOS devices.

Comment: @NightLeopard I understand you don't want to use a Smart Folder, but since iPhoto doesn't offer this feature, you might want to use a semi-manual approach. It involves using automator to modify the metadata of the pictures in a smart folder (adding a keyword that iPhoto understands). Let me know if you need more help with that and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Smart folders still make it easier in that I can manually add everything in it to the library. Not ideal, but it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Update: I figured out how to do it. See my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering my own question. Here's how you do it:

[image]

You need to set it a condition for `[size][space][unicode ×][space][size 2]`, for example: `320 × 480`. Not straightforward, but it works. However, it doesn't actually care which order you put the width and height, so this one will find 320x480 images as well as 480x320 images.

Comment: Even more specifically, that's a "unicode multiplication sign" (C397). Info [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm). The easiest way to get one, of course, is to cut and paste yours, above (or this one `×`). ;^) Neat trick; thanks!

Comment: This works also on the Photos.app, just that instead of "Any Text", the selection is just "Text".

Comment: @margusholland  I had trouble making it work in Photos.app; it would randomly select *some* of the pictures that matched the criteria. Also,  the order of the dimensions did matter.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Yes, I'm also seeing this behaviour, annoyingly. A separate smart album for filesnames ending in .PNG is a good way to find the disparities. I'll keep digging...

Answer (score 6):

iPhoto doesn't seem to have that capability in its Smart Folders, however, you can find the pictures using Finder.

You failed to mention what version of Mac OS X (or iPhoto) you have, but the following settings are available since Leopard as far as I can remember:

1. Open a new Finder window, and on the top menu, click:

   File -> New Smart Folder <kbd>⌥⌘N</kbd>
2. Now you need to add one or two conditions for this Smart Folder. You want to specify the width or height (or both) of the images. Click the (+) symbol:

   [image]
   <sub>*Note: the black cover is because I have some NDA protected names there*</sub>
3. On the little bar that appears (that says "Kind" "Equals"), click on Kind and select "**Other**". In the SearchBox of this sheet that appears, type **Pixel** and the results should look like this:

   [image: step2]
4. Now select **Pixel Height** and click OK. If you *also* want to specify the Width, repeat steps two and three.
5. Now change your values to reflect something like this:

   [image: step3]

You will want to change the Width/Height values. In the above example, I'm seeing all the images that are greater than 1920x1080.

<sub>*Notice I forgot to change 'is greater than' when taking the screenshot and therefore the width is using 'Equals'.*</sub>

You can **save** this Smart Folder (notice the tiny save button in the top right corner) and it will be automatically updated all the time. You can even drag it to your Sidebar for fast/easy access.

Sadly, iPhoto 9.2.x (latest at the time of writing), doesn't allow you to create a smart folder with these settings, which is kinda surprising if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Aperture (demo is OK) to set up the smart album. Aperture has more criteria that can be used (such as pixel dimensions).

iPhoto will still open the Library, and will display the Smart Album just fine with the correct files matched.

Note: you cannot edit the settings in iPhoto, you have to go back to Aperture if you wish to tweak the settings).

I used this approach today to set the following Pano smart album:

Aperture settings:
[image: Panoramas smart album]

Aperture display (cropped):
[image: Aperture]

iPhoto display (cropped):
[image: iPhoto]